# Getting xslt of the two xml's

Tags: xslt

One.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<todo-lists type='array'>
    <todo-list>
          <id type='integer'>10663712</id>
          <name>Pyramid</name>
          <todo-items type='array'>
                <todo-item>
                  <id type='integer'>67431502</id>
                  <content>General Items that you are working on. Enter brief description 
                    on what you worked on.</content>
                </todo-item>
                <todo-item>
                  <id type='integer'>78230534</id>
                  <content>Schedule FTPExport checking on Production.</content>
                </todo-item>
                <todo-item>
                  <id type='integer'>78230579</id>
                  <content>Adding Smartphone and MobileHandsets Sector on DEV</content>
                </todo-item>
                <todo-item>
                  <id type='integer'>78610242</id>
                  <content>Adding new Sectors on DEV.</content>
                </todo-item>
            </todo-items>   
    <todo-list> 
</todo-lists>
```

two.xml

```
<time-entries>
    <time-entry>
      <date type="date">2011-02-28</date>
      <description>Learn Ajax,Webservices,JSON in Javascript</description>
      <hours type="float">8.0</hours>
      <id type="integer">35458966</id>
      <person-id type="integer">6557642</person-id>
      <email-address>akumar@tekege.com</email-address>
      <project-id type="integer">1802011</project-id>
      <todo-item-id type="integer">67431502</todo-item-id>
    </time-entry>
    <time-entry>
      <date type="date">2011-02-28</date>
      <description>for testing purposes... Ranjeet</description>
      <hours type="float">1.25</hours>
      <id type="integer">35380151</id>
      <person-id type="integer">5949975</person-id>
      <email-address>rkumar@tekege.com</email-address>
      <project-id type="integer">1802011</project-id>
      <todo-item-id type="integer" nil="true"/>
    </time-entry>
    <time-entry>
      <date type="date">2011-02-28</date>
      <description>For Testing purposes....Ranjeet</description>
      <hours type="float">1.01667</hours>
      <id type="integer">35380081</id>
      <person-id type="integer">5949975</person-id>
      <email-address>rkumar@tekege.com</email-address>
      <project-id type="integer">1802011</project-id>
      <todo-item-id type="integer" nil="true">78230534</todo-item-id>
    </time-entry>
</time-entries>
```

answer.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<todo-lists type='array'>
    <todo-list>
          <id type='integer'>10663712</id>
          <name>Pyramid</name>
          <todo-items type='array'>
                <todo-item>
                  <id type='integer'>67431502</id>
                  <content>General Items that you are working on. Enter brief description 
                    on what you worked on.</content>
                  <description>Learn Ajax,Webservices,JSON in Javascript</description>  
                </todo-item>
                <todo-item>
                  <id type='integer'>78230534</id>
                  <content>Schedule FTPExport checking on Production.</content>
                  <description>For Testing purposes....Ranjeet</description>
                </todo-item>
                <todo-item>
                  <id type='integer'>78230579</id>
                  <content>Adding Smartphone and MobileHandsets Sector on DEV</content>
                </todo-item>
                <todo-item>
                  <id type='integer'>78610242</id>
                  <content>Adding new Sectors on DEV.</content>
                </todo-item>
            </todo-items>   
    <todo-list> 
</todo-lists>
```

Please get the answer.xml using xslt from the using one.xml and two.xml matching one element exist in both ie  one.xml having `<id type='integer'>67431502</id>` which match with the `<todo-item-id type="integer">67431502</todo-item-id>` of two.xml to get the answer.xml

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy XSLT solution that is based on the most fundamental XSLT design pattern -- the using and overriding of the identity rule. Extensive explanation is also provided.

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my" >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:doc2>
    <time-entries>
        <time-entry>
            <date type="date">2011-02-28</date>
            <description>Learn Ajax,Webservices,JSON in Javascript</description>
            <hours type="float">8.0</hours>
            <id type="integer">35458966</id>
            <person-id type="integer">6557642</person-id>
            <email-address>akumar@tekege.com</email-address>
            <project-id type="integer">1802011</project-id>
            <todo-item-id type="integer">67431502</todo-item-id>
        </time-entry>
        <time-entry>
            <date type="date">2011-02-28</date>
            <description>for testing purposes... Ranjeet</description>
            <hours type="float">1.25</hours>
            <id type="integer">35380151</id>
            <person-id type="integer">5949975</person-id>
            <email-address>rkumar@tekege.com</email-address>
            <project-id type="integer">1802011</project-id>
            <todo-item-id type="integer" nil="true"/>
        </time-entry>
        <time-entry>
            <date type="date">2011-02-28</date>
            <description>For Testing purposes....Ranjeet</description>
            <hours type="float">1.01667</hours>
            <id type="integer">35380081</id>
            <person-id type="integer">5949975</person-id>
            <email-address>rkumar@tekege.com</email-address>
            <project-id type="integer">1802011</project-id>
            <todo-item-id type="integer" nil="true">78230534</todo-item-id>
        </time-entry>
    </time-entries>
</my:doc2>

 <xsl:variable name="vDoc2" select="document('')/*/my:doc2"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="todo-item[id = document('')/*/my:doc2/*/*/id]">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select=
   "node()|@*|$vDoc2/*/*[id = current()/id]/description"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<todo-lists type='array'>
    <todo-list>
        <id type='integer'>10663712</id>
        <name>Pyramid</name>
        <todo-items type='array'>
            <todo-item>
                <id type='integer'>67431502</id>
                <content>General Items that you are working on. Enter brief description
                on what you worked on.</content>
            </todo-item>
            <todo-item>
                <id type='integer'>78230534</id>
                <content>Schedule FTPExport checking on Production.</content>
            </todo-item>
            <todo-item>
                <id type='integer'>78230579</id>
                <content>Adding Smartphone and MobileHandsets Sector on DEV</content>
            </todo-item>
            <todo-item>
                <id type='integer'>78610242</id>
                <content>Adding new Sectors on DEV.</content>
            </todo-item>
        </todo-items>
    </todo-list>
</todo-lists>
```

**produces the wanted, correct answer:**

```
<todo-lists type="array">
   <todo-list>
      <id type="integer">10663712</id>
      <name>Pyramid</name>
      <todo-items type="array">
         <todo-item>
            <id type="integer">67431502</id>
            <content>General Items that you are working on. Enter brief description
                on what you worked on.</content>
         </todo-item>
         <todo-item>
            <id type="integer">78230534</id>
            <content>Schedule FTPExport checking on Production.</content>
         </todo-item>
         <todo-item>
            <id type="integer">78230579</id>
            <content>Adding Smartphone and MobileHandsets Sector on DEV</content>
         </todo-item>
         <todo-item>
            <id type="integer">78610242</id>
            <content>Adding new Sectors on DEV.</content>
         </todo-item>
      </todo-items>
   </todo-list>
</todo-lists>
```

**Explanation**:

1. For convenience the second XML document is embedded in the stylesheet. In any practical implementation it will reside in its own file -- this will cause only the argument to the `document()` function calls to be replaced with the particular file URL.
2. The identity rule/template copies every node "as-is".
3. The identity rule is overriden by a single template matching those `todo-item` elements the value of whose `id` child is the same as the value of the `id` child of some `time-entry` element in the second document.
4. For all such elements the processing is as with the identity template, but an additional child is added after the current children -- this is the `description` child of the corresponding `time-entry` from the second document.

Answer (score 0):

With keys, this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kDescriptionById"
             match="description"
             use="../todo-item-id"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vSource2" select="document('two.xml')"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="todo-item">
        <xsl:variable name="vCurrent" select="."/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$vSource2">
                <xsl:apply-templates
                 select="key('kDescriptionById',$vCurrent/id)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<todo-lists type="array">
    <todo-list>
        <id type="integer">10663712</id>
        <name>Pyramid</name>
        <todo-items type="array">
            <todo-item>
                <id type="integer">67431502</id>
                <content>General Items that you are working on. Enter brief description                      on what you worked on.</content>
                <description>Learn Ajax,Webservices,JSON in Javascript</description>
            </todo-item>
            <todo-item>
                <id type="integer">78230534</id>
                <content>Schedule FTPExport checking on Production.</content>
                <description>For Testing purposes....Ranjeet</description>
            </todo-item>
            <todo-item>
                <id type="integer">78230579</id>
                <content>Adding Smartphone and MobileHandsets Sector on DEV</content>
            </todo-item>
            <todo-item>
                <id type="integer">78610242</id>
                <content>Adding new Sectors on DEV.</content>
            </todo-item>
        </todo-items>
    </todo-list>
</todo-lists>
```

**Note**: `key()` XSLT function works against the context node's document.

Comment: But the answer.xml show the all the description text beneath every content not according to the matching   one.xml having <id type='integer'>67431502</id> which match with the <todo-item-id type="integer">67431502</todo-item-id> of two.xml to get the answer.xml

Comment: @satya: I don't understand your complain. Isn't the exact same desired output you'd provided?